# REGEX match - look ahead assertions

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to parse a file and capture all the "sent" dates. The format of the dates vary, so I am looking for patterns and adding the format ( to give to Time::Piece::strptime ) .
My date patterns are as follows  "Mon Nov 13 12:34:10 2006" or "Tuesday, November 14, 2006 10:58 AM".
I used a look ahead assertion to see if the end was AM or PM and handle the two cases
I was reading the file line by line and writing the following code:

```
    print "$2<-\n" if $line =~ /(Sent):\s*([^\n]+)(?<=AM|PM)$/;
    print "$2<- \n" if $line =~ /(Sent):\s*([^\n]+)(?<!AM|PM)$/;
```

The problem I ran into was that sometimes I have a whitespace at the end of the lines before the newlines. Like so "Tuesday, November 14, 2006 10:58 AM ", or "Mon Nov 13 12:34:10 2006 ". I can't figure out how to write the look ahead and see if does or doesnot have an AM or PM and then a possible space at the end. It ends up matching both times. 
I know I could break the loop ( put a proper block when matching and then break out with a "next" once I match the first one ) but I really want to understand what the regex engine is doing. Also, why does $2 contain the AM and PM ? 
Thanks

Comment: So do you want to capture `AM` and `PM` into Group 2 with your first regex? Right now, you may use `/(Sent):\s*(.*[AP]M)\h*$/` and `/(Sent):(?!.*[AP]M\h*$)\s*(.+)/`, but you need to precise these patterns according to what should land in the capturing groups.

Comment: Why don't you just do something like `if ($line =~ /AM|PM/) { ... } else { ... }` to handle the two formats?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( my ($sent) = $line =~ /Sent:\s*(.*)/ ) {
   print "= $sent\n" if $sent =~ /[AP]M\s*$/;
   print "! $sent\n" if $sent !~ /[AP]M\s*$/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code extract dates correctly?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $pattern = qr/Sent:\s+(.*?)\s*$/;

my $date;

while( <DATA> ) {
    next if /^$/;

    $date = undef;
    $date = $1 if /$pattern/;

    say "[$date]" if $date;
}

__DATA__
Sent: Mon Nov 13 12:34:10 2006 
Sent: Fri Apr 13 12:34:10 2007 
Sent: Sat Jun 13 12:34:10 2009 
Some extra line to skip
Sent: Tuesday, November 14, 2006 10:58 AM 
Sent: Monday, November 16, 2006  6:20 AM 
Sent: Thursday, November 17, 2006  8:18 PM 
Other extra line to skip
Sent: Wednesday, December 4,  2006  1:06 PM
```

output

```
[Mon Nov 13 12:34:10 2006]
[Fri Apr 13 12:34:10 2007]
[Sat Jun 13 12:34:10 2009]
[Tuesday, November 14, 2006 10:58 AM]
[Monday, November 16, 2006  6:20 AM]
[Thursday, November 17, 2006  8:18 PM]
[Wednesday, December 4,  2006  1:06 PM]
```